# What is reduced time precision and is it adding time to the results?

Tags: javascript, profiling, performance-testing

I just read that when using Date.now() it adds 2 ms reduced time precision. From the documentation:

> Reduced time precision
> To offer protection against timing attacks and
> fingerprinting, the precision of Date.now() might get rounded
> depending on browser settings. In Firefox, the
> privacy.reduceTimerPrecision preference is enabled by default and
> defaults to 20µs in Firefox 59; in 60 it will be 2ms.

Does that mean when I check the duration of my code using Date.now() it will add from 0 to 2ms to the difference?

No, I don't have performance.now in my Javascript environment. Don't ask.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes. my code runs and reports 1 to 2ms

Comment: I am not seeing any variation in Firefox 101 with this code: `[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(() => { console.log(Date.now()) })`